# How come my audio tag loads the source when it is hard coded, but not when provided by Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've created a component, and in that component is an audio tag. I've been trying to pass the file path of the mp3 to the component from its parent, but the audio element doesn't seem to be able to load the file successfully for some reason. The element just ends up greyed out, and I don't get any kind of error. I know the properties are being passed successfully because I'm also passing in the title of the track, and that loads just fine in the component. However, if I hardcode the same path in for the source, then it works fine. Which isn't a big deal, but I have 11 tracks to do and it would be much easier with a v-for statement.

Here's my parent component:

```
    <template>
    <div container>
        <div class=banner>
            <img src="../assets/CryptoLogo2.svg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="albumcontainer">
          <div class="covercontainer"><img src="../assets/TIADCover(Final).png"/></div>
          <div class="arrow"></div>
          <div class="tracklistcontainer">
            <table class="tracklist">
              <tr class="track" v-for="track in tracks" :key="track.file"  style="padding: 20px;">
                <td>
                  <player :name="track.name" :file="track.file" />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bio">
          <p>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
          <div class="footericons">
            <img src="../assets/icons/Facebook.svg" />
            <img src="../assets/icons/Instagram.svg" />
            <img src="../assets/icons/Twitter.svg" />
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import player from './player'
    export default {
  name: "Album1",
  data() {
    return {
      tracks: [
        {
          name: '5G',
          file: '../assets/tracks/5G.mp3'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  components:{
    player
  }
};
</script>
```

And then the component with the audio tag:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h3>{{ name }}</h3>
        <audio controls controlsList="nodownload">
            <source ref="player" v-bind:src="file" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    name: "player",
    props: {
        name: {
            type: String,
            default: null
        },
        file:{
            type: String,
            default: null
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Here you can see that my data is being passed successfully.

[image: Here you can see that my data is being passed successfully.]

And you see that the source attribute is being loaded correctly as well.

[image: And you see that the source attribute is being loaded correctly as well.]

This is what I get, and you can see the h3 loads fine, so I know the data is being passed. But the element is greyed out.

[image: This is what I get, and you can see the h3 loads fine, so I know the data is being passed. But the element is greyed out.]

To test it out, I tried just hard coding the file path:

```
<source src="../assets/tracks/5G.mp3">
```

And that works just fine:

[image: It's working perfectly.]

But I don't want to do it like that because I have about 11 tracks to do, so I would like for it to load from the data being passed so that I can reuse the component. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using something like this in your Vue `v-for` I use this when `src` is not loading on the `img` tag.

```
:src="getSrc(x.src)"
```

---

```
  methods: {
   getSrc(src) {
     return require("../assets/" + src);
   }
 }
```

Comment: So, I tried that and it seemed like it was a good idea, but now I get this error: vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1832 Error: Cannot find module '../assets/tracks/5G.mp3'. It seems like this is the underlying issue after all. I just don't get why it works hard coded but not through Vue.

Comment: check the path, might be `./assets/...`

Comment: The path is fine because when the exact same path is hard coded, it works just fine.

Comment: There's is something wrong in your logic related to the lifecycle hooks, I'm almost sure. Edit to update the code

Comment: Okay, I edited the code to take out that life cycle hook because it's no longer in my code and I'm still having that same issue.

Comment: So, I decided to just take my implementation in a completely different direction because I couldn't figure this out. On in my new code, I was able to use this: song.src= require('../assets/tracks/' + file); And this works perfectly. So I'm going to give an upvote because even though you didn't get the overall issue, it looks like you were on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Your watch function on file prop is never triggered because your file name is static, it never triggers a change on the watcher, before mounting the component, at least in the code you provided it is that way.

[From Vue.js API vm.$watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch)
Watch an expression or a computed function on the Vue instance for changes. The callback gets called with the new value and the old value.

Comment: Actually, ignore that method. That was just me testing a solution but I was going in the wrong direction.